# SQL Server 2012: does OPENDATASOURCE not accept variables, only literal strings?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2012 query that uses OPENDATASOURCE. I want to build the init string separately and then call OPENDATASOURCE, so that I can avoid using dynamic SQL. The command I use is like this:

```
set @connection_string = 'Data Source='+ @ServerName + ';User ID=' + @UserName + ';Password=' + @Pass

select  *
from    opendatasource('SQLOLEDB', @connection_string)...
```

however, when I run this, I get the error

```
Incorrect syntax near '@connection_string'. Expecting STRING, or TEXT_LEX.
```

Am I not allowed to use a variable in OPENDATASOURCE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OPENDATASOURCE does not accept variables for its arguments.

Source : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx

Comment: @user884248 Read Erland Sommarskog's discussion of dynamic SQL for a workaround.  See the section for "OPENQUERY," which also does not accept variables:  http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part